# WooCommerce API Challenges: ’empty_data’ Error IssuesinPython, Tested in Pure Python

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Why does WooCommerce occasionally display the error

> {‘code’: ’empty_data’, ‘message’: ‘Not enough data to create this user.’, ‘data’: {‘status’: 400}}

when posting customer details through Python to WooCommerce? This error seems to occur without any apparent cause, despite ensuring that all necessary details have been provided. Could you please provide a comprehensive solution to address these challenges?

Below is the Python code snippet utilized for the customer export:

This is tested with a single Python file, and tested in latest WooCommerce live to create an account head to https://woo.com/feature-request/a-stand-alone-free-trial/

I tested in this so i can get the latest WooCommerce features

```
from woocommerce import API

url = "https://woo-sweetly-casual-music.wpcomstaging.com/"
consumer_key = "ck_4d0fcbf47bc4a00e0c22d7577d75a7831ac14245"
consumer_secret = "cs_a503bc3a1d73264660e4dd46749bfabc41eacf52"

wcapi = API(
    url=url,
    consumer_key=consumer_key,
    consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
    version="wc/v3"
)

data = {
    "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "username": "john.doe",
    "billing": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "company": "",
        "address_1": "969 Market",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "state": "CA",
        "postcode": "94103",
        "country": "US",
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
    },
    "shipping": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "company": "",
        "address_1": "969 Market",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "state": "CA",
        "postcode": "94103",
        "country": "US"
    }
}

response = wcapi.post("customers", data)
print(response.json())
```

The response i am getting

> {'code': 'empty_data', 'message': 'Not enough data to create this user.', 'data': {'status': 400}}